# Paginate data returned by facebook graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I am using PHP SDK 5.0. I have been able to pull posts from my FB page and display it on my site [with this code](http://pastebin.com/bNPE4y76) below. I need help to achieve pagination of the results returned by this code.

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__. '/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
    'default_access_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
]);
$request = $fb->request('GET','/500px/feed/', array('fields' => 'created_time,message', 'limit' => '3',));

try {
    $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
    $data_array = $response->getDecodedBody();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Facebook returns the next and previous links with every feed-result, like in the example below. How can I get pagination using those ? Or is there a better alternative.

```
[data] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
             (
               [created_time] => 2015-09-23T17:00:53+0000
               [message] => some message pulled from the post
               [id] => 57284451149_10152992926641150
              )
        )

[paging] => Array
                (
         [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/57284451149/feed?fields=created_time,message&limit=1&since=1443027653&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx&__paging_token=enc_xxxxxxxxxxxx&__previous=1
         [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/57284451149/feed?fields=created_time,message&limit=1&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx&until=1443027653&__paging_token=enc_xxxxxxxxxxxx
)
```

I am still learning PHP, and at this point I have no clue how to go beyond this. Ideally there would be three results per page and the results would display on the same page. If not a solution, I would really appreciate pseudo codes or helpful suggestions or a roadmap which would help me do it myself.

---

**TEMP SOLUTION** - I could be on wrong track, but here is what I have done as a temporary solution. Seems like facebook does all the work, eg offset etc and provides us a calculated url, and all we need to do is work with the provided urls.

```
//set your url parameters here       
    function fetchUrl($url){
               if(is_callable('curl_init')){
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    $feedData = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    }
                    return $feedData;
             }

                if(isset($_POST['nextLink'])){
                $url = $_POST['nextLink'];
                } elseif(isset($_POST['prevLink'])){
                $url = $_POST['prevLink'];
                } else {
                $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/'.$pageID.'/feed?fields='.$fields.'&limit='.$limit.'&access_token='.$accessToken;
                }

         $json_object = fetchUrl($url);
         $FBdata = json_decode($json_object, true);
         //parse the received data in your desired format
         //display data

//get the next link, construct and set a url
$nextLink = $FBdata['paging']['next'];
$prevLink = $FBdata['paging']['previous'];

//Your next and previous form here
```

I would use http `GET` method but i don't prefer ugly long urls so I am using `POST` method to get `next` and `previous` urls. Note that I using cURL instead of PHP SDK. This is a simplified example and needs more work.

I am not writing this as an answer because this is just a woraround not a solution, I am still looking to do it using **PHP SDK**. I just could not gt hold of `SDK` generated url. Any inputs ?